# angular service across multiple controller without duplicatefunctions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I was wondering if you could help me out.  Basically I have a service which stores a value called name that is to be used across multiple directives.  My issue is that it is used across approx 7 directives hence in each of the 7 corresponding controllers I have a function called getName which makes a call to myService.getName to return the name so as it can be used in the view.  This seems like alot of duplicate code for me , 7 identical functions in 7 different controllers (because I shouldnt directly make a call to the service via the html).  I was wondering what the best practice is so as I dont have duplicate functions.  Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A way to define settings for your whole application, is to store them inside `$rootScope`

Inside one of your controllers, you will have to declare those new settings :

```
$rootScope.applicationSettings = {};
$rootScope.applicationSettings.importantName = "some name";
```

And inside your views, as far as you don't have a scope with the object "applicationSettings" defined inside it, the following markup will work :

```
{{applicationSettings.importantName}}
```

And inside every controller, as far as you've injected $rootScope, you will be able to get or set `$rootScope.applicationSettings.importantName`

Comment: I appreciate your input and I'm not saying its wrong but I was just hoping there was a more elegant solution than putting it on the routescope, I try to avoid adding stuff there if at all possible.  Thanks again for your input :)

Comment: i let my answer here, although it doesn't suit you. You can achieve this with a custom $filter, but I don't have any code to help you